# how to add back slash(\) before double quote(") in string

Tags: java, string

Guys I want to add \ before double quote " in a string..

for example :-

```
String s = "FB "Party" event";
```

Output should be:-

```
String Output = "FB \"Party\" event"
```

I tried a lot but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain what "no luck" means. In other words, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what your problem is. After all, your first Java line is invalid syntax.

Comment: "\\" will add a slash and "\"" (exclude outer quotes) will add a quote without messing up command. In other words, `String s = "FB \\ \"Par...` will give output as `FB \ "Par...`. Please learn about `Escape Characters` in java.

Comment: use -> "FB \\\"Party\\\" event" read on escape character....

Answer (score 2):

Try this `"FB \\\"Party\\\" event"`
First two slashes is one slash and \" is double quote

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple technique..

use escape character. Like for your case it would be something like

```
String input = "FB \\\"Party\\\" event";
    System.out.println(input);
```